# Como prevenir que cambie de vista Viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Buenos días/tardes/noche. Estoy haciendo una aplicación con un **Viewpager**, funciona todo correcto, pero lo que quiere es que el usuario no pueda acceder a la siguiente vista mientras no llene el campo que esta en la primera vista.

**MainActivity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_onboarding);
    vp_onboarding = findViewById(R.id.ob_pager);

    setupViewPager(vp_onboarding);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new onboarding_one());
    adapter.addFragment(new onboarding_two());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

static class Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();

    public Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        mFragments.add(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }
}
// Permitir acceso a la primera vista (Onboarding_one)
//TODO: bloquear el acceso a la siguiente vista
```

**Fragment_Onboarding_One**

```
If(editext.lenght > 0){
  // Desbloquear el acceso al **Fragment_onboarding_two**
}
```